# Do not see system environment variables in C# on MacOS, .Net Core 3.1 / .Net 5.0. (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to use an environment variable in a code.
First of all, I have set them in ~/.zprofile, I can receive them via `getenv` in shell and via relevant methods in Java, NodeJS, Python.

However, this doesn't work with C#.

---

What I tried:

```
foreach (String name in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process).Keys)
{
    Console.Write(name + "="); 
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)[name]);
}
```

This does print several env variables. Not the ones I need.

---

And when I try:

```
foreach (String name in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.User).Keys)
{
    // Never get here                                                                                             
}

foreach (String name in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine).Keys)
{
    // Never get here                                                                                                }
}
```

This prints nothing.

---

How can I find my environment variables?
Thanks.

Edit: Restarting Visual Studio via GUI didn't help. The env variables were not new.

Comment: The documentation for both `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine` and `EnvironmentVariableTarget.User` explicitly says: "This value should be used on .NET implementations running on Windows systems only."

Answer (score 5):

Once I closed Visual Studio and opened it from the terminal

```
open /Applications/Visual\ Studio.app
```

I saw all of my env variables here:
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
which is the same as:
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()

So the issue seems specific to Visual studio on Mac, with a specific solution.

Comment: I would say, the environment variables of a process won't change after the process has started. The child processes also inherit them. That's why restarting VS helped.

Comment: Restarting via GUI didn't help. Only starting visual-studio from the shell helped.

Comment: I'm not aware of how VS GUI can be restarted on Mac. Does it completely stop and start a new process?

Comment: "have set them in ~/.zprofile" is the actual cause of the problem, as you were setting the environment variables only for zsh. That's why zsh in Terminal and all child processes (launching VS for Mac from there) can see the variables. However, when you open VS for Mac from places like Launchpad, zsh is not involved so those zsh only variables can never appear.

Comment: Lex Li. Where else, other than .zprofile/.bash profile can I set environment variables in a Unix system?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code

`String API_Key = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("API_KEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)`

to

`String API_Key = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("API_KEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)`

worked for me on MacOS because [EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=net-7.0#fields) should be used on **.NET implementations running on Windows systems only**.

Answer (score -1):

As of version 17.5.1 Visual Studio 2022 for Mac you can go into project  Properties >> Run >> Configuration >> Default >> Environment Variables section on the modal, you can click Add variables and values there where VS can see that.  That way you don't need to launch it from terminal.  <s>Now for myself, I got the path right, but my unit test cannot launch the nuget chrome driver.  I need to find out why chromedriver.exe is copied to the output folder (bin/Debug) and not an Unix/mac executable. Geckodriver works fine though.</s>

Comment: This seems irrelevant to the question being asked, which is about user-specific and machine-specific environment variables, which just aren't supported other than on Windows (as documented).

Comment: The edit still doesn't make it relevant to this question...